# Build failed error with react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobile-development

I'm trying to setup react navigation package for react native but when I start my app I got this error:

> BU�LD FAILED in 1m 24s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> e: C:\react-native\Navigation\navigation\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.kt: (247, 92): Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details
>
> ## Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
>
> ## Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BU�LD FAILED in 1m 24s
>
> at makeError (C:\react-native\Navigation\navigation\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at C:\react-native\Navigation\navigation\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async runOnAllDevices (C:\react-native\Navigation\navigation\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\react-native\Navigation\navigation\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I'm following the instructions on the react navigation docs but I don't know how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to setup react navigation for a number of times following exacltly what the guide said but I still get this error.